# 20 Duplicate Symbols for Architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture

[image: The image showing the 20 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64]

I have using Superpowered Library after importing the classes it showing the error.

I have investigate a lot on google about this.

Any help will be precious.

Comment: In your project settings, navigate to Your target > Build Phases > Compile Sources and make sure there are no duplicated files in there.

Comment: I have already checked this,there was no duplicated files :( @JDx

Comment: ok, is superpower a static library? Make sure it hasn't been accidentally added to your project twice. Also what is your USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS and LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS set to?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove -**Objc** linker flag from Other Linker flag from Build Setting Tab.

[image]